# wpf mvvm - master detail in one view best implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, master-detail

I have a view which contains a datagrid. Below the datagrid I have some controls to edit the properties of the selected item (lets say a manager) from the datagrid.

So I have a property that is bound to the datagrid SelectedItem:

A Manager has for example a property called Name.
So when a manager is selected. a textbox below the datagrid has to be bound to the name property I can do this in xaml like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedManager.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The problem is that I like to implement some extra code when the value of SelectedManager.Name changes so I need a property in my ViewModel like this:

```
private Manager _selectedManager;
public Manager SelectedManager
{
    get { return _selectedManager; }
    set
    {
        _selectedManager = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedManager");
    }
}
```

So when SelectedManager changes this would not update the ManagerName property ofcourse. I have 3 solutions and I would like to know what you think about these or do you have a better way. My solutuions are:

1: When the SelectedManager is set I can call RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);
This will update all bindings.

2: When the SelectedManager is set I can call RaisePropertyChanged("ManagerName"));
This will update the binding for the specific property (but infact Manager contains more properties so I have to do that for every property).

I Don't think solution 1 and 2 are clean so solution 3 is:

Creat an innerclass DetailsViewModel (so this basicly a childviewmodel) to handle the details properties. Bind the datacontext of the detail controls to an instance of DetailsViewModel. This looks a great solution, but the problem is, I like to access the ParentViewModel from the ChildViewModel, and I don't think passing the ParentViewModel to the ChildViewModel is a good idea.

So what will be cleanest solution, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Screenshot of the view:
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/21/2xXws6.png

Comment: SelectedManager is not a DependencyProeprty is just a simple Property pls edit your question

Comment: *I don't think passing the ParentViewModel to the ChildViewModel is a good idea*... why not, there's nothing wrong with doing that. It is commonly done in MVVM. Another (simpler) possibility is to put your manipulation code into the `Manager.Name` setter.

Comment: @Sheridan the manipultion code I'd like to put in are things like `Command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`. So I can't do that in `Manager.Name`